# Как работать в Django с БД Access?

Tags: python, база-данных, django, python-3.x, access

Нужно организовать работу в `Django` с БД в формате `Access`. Судя по официальной документации, `Django ORM` поддерживает работу с `PostgreSQL, SQLite 3, MySQL, Oracle`. Читал про экспорт `Access` в `MySQL`, но искомая БД содержит файлы-вложения, как их корректно перенести? Если же оставить `Access`, возможно ли с ней работать в `Django`? Если да, то как?

Update:
Прочел, что нужно установить модуль `pyodbc`, максимальная версия `python` для него - 3.3.
Пытаюсь установить на Windows `python 3.3.5` + `Django`.
`Python` установился, добавил переменные окружения, создал виртуальное окружение, установил `pip` и `django 1.9.2`. При попытке создать новый проект выдается ошибка импорта `find_spec`, если я правильно понимаю, эта библиотека начала использоваться лишь с `python 3.4`.

```
django-admin startproject myproject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python33\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python33\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python33\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps
  File "c:\python33\lib\site-packages\django\apps\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .config import AppConfig
  File "c:\python33\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.utils.module_loading import module_has_submodule
  File "c:\python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 67, in <module>
    from importlib.util import find_spec as importlib_find
ImportError: cannot import name find_spec
```

Update1: Т.к. эта проблема возникает для `django 1.9`, удалил `django 1.9.1`, установил 1.8, ошибка импорта исчезла.

Update2:
Установил `pyodbc`, при попытке `import pyodbc` возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

Update3:
Пытаюсь сделать вот так
https://github.com/EBNull/django-pyodbc-access

```
Ошибка при `python manage.py inspectdb` 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 868, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 853, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 980, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python33\access\pyodbc\base.py", line 8
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Update:**
уточню - мне нужно работать с БД Access, т.е. выполнять запросы и получать данные из нее, но хранить собственно БД Django можно в более стандартном формате. 
Таким образом, в `settings.py` пока оставил все по умолчанию, установил `pyodbc`, `django-pyodbc`, пробую через консоль выполнить запрос:

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> ACCESS_DATABASE_FILE = "C:\\путь\\db.accdb"
>>> ODBC_CONN_STR = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;" % ACCESS_DATABASE_FILE
>>> conn = pyodbc.connect(ODBC_CONN_STR)
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("SELECT [Ид] FROM [Пользователи])
```

И здесь вылетает из консоли питона в виртуальное окружение, если перед этими операциями выполняю `chcp 65001`, если же не делаю этого, ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Загвоздка в том, что и названия таблиц, и названия полей - на русском языке. Вообще и сама таблица имеет кириллическое название, но пока для теста использую англоязычное. Попробовал заключить русскоязычные названия в квадратные скобки, не помогло.

Comment: Django 1.9 работает только с версиями 2.7.х, 3.4.х и 3.5.х

Comment: @Shamanis спасибо, уже понял) В посте добавил дополнение в конце. Интересно, что pip сам выбрал версию 1.9, теперь буду знать, что нужно указывать версию ниже вручную

Comment: Лучше всего к проекту прилагать файл requirments.txt со всеми зависимостями и нужными версиями, потом самому же удобней будет устанавливать все ч/з параметр -r. PIP установил просто последнюю версию, он не всегда корректно проверяет версию питон с классифаерсами пакетов.

Comment: @Shamanis спасибо за подсказку. Установил `pyodbc` (по крайней мере так говорит `pip` и `easy_install`, где можно посмотреть наличие файлов библиотеки? устанавливаю внутри виртуального окружения), при попытке `import pyodbc ` возникает ошибка:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pyodbc'`

Comment: Установите пакет django-pyodbc и в ENGINE пропишите django_pyodbc.

Comment: @Shamanis спасибо, помогло. Осталась проблема с кириллическими названиями таблиц и полей. При выполнении запроса ошибка: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 0: invalid continuation byte